# Cannot commit or push to GitHub due to 'seekret' not being a Git command

Tags: bash, git, github, zsh, commit

I've been encountering a persistent issue while trying to commit and push my code to GitHub. I'm working on a Mac, and whenever I attempt a commit or push in VS Code, I get the following error:

Git: git: 'seekret' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

I've tried to resolve this issue:

1. Checked both global (**`~/.gitconfig`**) and repository-specific (**`.git/config`**) Git configurations to see if the 'seekret' command is being invoked - found nothing related to 'seekret'.
2. Checked shell configuration files (like **`.bashrc`** and **`.zshrc`**) for any Git or 'seekret' related configurations - also found nothing related to 'seekret'.
3. Checked the hooks in the local repository (**`ls .git/hooks`**) and found nothing named 'seekret'.
4. Uninstalled and reinstalled Git, but the issue persists.

I'm not sure what to do next. I suspect this might have something to do with my environment, but I'm not sure how to track down the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I believe you're asking for a breakdown of the steps taken and the expectations at each step. Here's the summary:

1. **Checking global and repository-specific Git configurations**: I guided you to check the global Git configuration file (located at **`~/.gitconfig`**) and the configuration file of your specific repository (**`.git/config`**) to see if the 'seekret' command was being invoked there. We expected to find any 'seekret' related settings here that could cause the error, but found none.
2. **Checking shell configuration files**: The **`.bashrc`** and **`.zshrc`** files were inspected for any Git or 'seekret' related configurations. Again, we were looking for any 'seekret' related settings that might cause the error. The expectation was that if 'seekret' was mentioned in these files, removing or altering those lines could resolve the issue. But we didn't find any such mentions.
3. **Checking Git hooks in the local repository**: Git hooks are scripts that Git executes before or after events like **`commit`**, **`push`**, and others. It's possible that a pre-commit or pre-push hook was trying to execute a 'seekret' command. By checking the contents of the **`.git/hooks`** directory, we were hoping to find a hook file related to 'seekret'. However, no such file was found.
4. **Reinstalling Git**: Lastly, I suggested reinstalling Git in case the installation was somehow corrupted or misconfigured to use 'seekret'. We expected that a fresh install of Git might resolve the issue. However, the error still persists after the reinstallation.

At each of these steps, we were hoping to find the source of the 'seekret' command. However, despite these efforts, we were unable to locate any such configuration or script, which is why the error message remains puzzling.

Comment: What exactly you mean by `pushing in VSCode`. I don't know what extensions did you install in your code editor, but my first guess is that some extension wants to use executable `git-seekret` (cause if you make executable `git-mycommand` and add it to $PATH, you can then run `git mycommand`). I can also see that there already exists such [command on github](https://github.com/apuigsech/git-seekret).

Comment: In regards to "pushing in VSCode," I'm referring to using Visual Studio Code's Git integration to commit and push changes. The git-seekret command seems related to an extension or custom command, but I haven't installed any Git extensions requiring or referencing it. I've disabled Git-related extensions and checked configuration files but found no references. I've searched extensively for unintentional git-seekret installation or its presence from another extension. Anything else I can look for? @kadewu

Comment: There must be clearly something that want to use `git-seekret` either hooks or some custom script. I would suggest to try using git without VSCode and on fresh new repository and check if error persist.

Comment: @kadewu I've had this error before. This is my second repo/project in getting this error. The first repo was using mainly JS, and this one is using mainly Python

Comment: Doesn't matter what language you are using. And I don't know what are those projects (new one? you cloned them?) I will repeat my suggestion, check if error persist on new initialized repository when using git commands in shell, no IDE/code editor involved.

Comment: And if error persist, reinstall git and make sure to clear caches etc. (but I don't think that issue is there and rather believe that new fresh repository will be working). If new initialized repository will be working, then that means, you missed usage of `git-seekret` in the previous ones.